# Full text search order by text length

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a search box which allow users to enter a partial string and show an auto complete for the whole name.

Basically I want to do `WHERE LIKE %partial%`. But since the `LIKE` query can't make use of index when there is a leading wildcard, I ended up using full text index

My full text query looks like `CONTAINS(ColumnName, 'partial*')`

This works well until I had to introduce sorting. The returned result needs to be sorted based on the string length.

```
CONTAINS(ColumnName, 'partial*') ORDER BY LEN(ColumnName)
```

The performance stinks since LEN has to be dynamically calculated followed by a sort. I tried creating a calculated column and indexed it, but it did not help much.

The table contains around 100k rows (which is not a huge one) and I wonder how I can tune the index to speed this up.

Comment: What if you added a persisted computed column? Then you could simply order by the computed value.

Comment: @SeanLange I did. I added a computed column = LEN(ColumnName) and indexed it. But it did not help much. Probably because the length is pretty uniform distributed.

Comment: Was your computed column persisted? Posting the ddl for the table would be a HUGE help here.

Comment: @SeanLange looks like its not. I will give persist column a shot a bit later

Comment: If it isn't persisted it will have to perform that calculation every time a row is read. There are times this is good, and times when this is bad. Sounds like a bad thing in your case. :)

Comment: @SeanLange looks like persisted column is the answer. if you want to type up one real quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you said you have a computed column you should make sure that it is persisted. When a computed column is not persisted it has to make the calculation for every row. This essentially makes your query nonSARGable. When having the column persisted the value is stored and the index can be properly utilized.